# Should the values be rounded in this probability question?

Tags: probability

I had the following excersice in my exam:

> There are $60$ men and $140$ women working at a company. On average, $8\%$ of men are color blind and $0.5\%$ of women are color blind. If you pick one random person from the company, what is the probability that he or she will be color blind?

So using proportion method I counted how many men out of $140$ would be color blind on average:

$100 - 8$

$60 - x$

$100x = 480$

$x = 4,8$

and then I rounded the value to $5$ (thinking that there can't be a $0.8$ man).

Using the same method I got $0.7$ for women and rounded it to $1$.

So my final answer was
$$\dfrac{5+1}{200}=\dfrac{6}{200}=\dfrac{3}{100}.$$

Was I wrong in asuming that the values must be rounded? Is the correct answer 
$$\dfrac{4,8+0,7}{200}=\dfrac{5.5}{200}=\dfrac{1.1}{40}?$$

Comment: You can't take a round value. I think that the comment that men and women have a given probability is the probability of the general population, not the one of the people working in the company.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I should not have rounded the value and the correct answer for this particular problem is 1,1/40?

Comment: Yes. I would express it in term of percentage, but this answer is the right one.

Comment: $\frac{5.5}{200}=\frac{2.75}{100}=2.75\%$

Comment: The calculation leads to the "expected value". "Expected" means, repeating the test many often under the same conditions and taking the average over those reults, leads to the expected value. This value is, in general, not an integer. If you would have to guess the number of persons, it would be best to guess the rounded expected value because the actual value is likely to be near the expected value.